# Get last x rows in ascending order

Tags: sql, mysqli

This selects the last 7 rows by their id.
They are displayed as

id5

id4

id3

id2

id1

I'd like it reversed if possible, to work in a  chat style way where the latest message is displayed on the bottom. Is there any way of doing this SQL wise and not use php?

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM drchat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $drchat = $drchat . $row['string'] . "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM drchat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7 is the sql statement you are using. If You want it reversed than use: SELECT * FROM drchat ORDER BY id LIMIT 7

It will then sort asc (default)

Comment: yes but I have more than 7 rows. I want to always have the last 7 rows by id printed not the first 7 ones...

Comment: Try this it will give you what you want.

SELECT * FROM drchat WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM drchat ORDER BY id DESC) ORDER BY id LIMIT 7

The above works on the mySql version that I have.
 
SELECT * FROM drchat WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM drchat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7) ORDER BY id 

May also work on the mysql version you are using. If not stick with the first